# RewritePath for 404 response?

Tags: .net, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite module that matches the requested path to a slug in my db. If it doesn't match anything I want to return a 404 error code and rewrite the url to my 404 page.

The problem is that if I set the response status to 404 the rewrite doesn't take place and IIS returns it's default 404 error page instead of the content from the page I am rewriting to.

```
var slug = db.Slugs.FirstOrDefault(x => SqlMethods.Like(x.SlugValue, app.Request.Path));
if (slug == null)
{
    app.Response.Status = "404 Not Found";
    app.Context.RewritePath(Settings.NotFoundPage, true);
    return;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

(If I comment out the Status and rewrite the URL to my NotFoundPage it works fine but then the return code is not 404)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can move your `app.Response.Status = "404 Not Found";` code to the code-behind for your PageNotFound page instead, and that will work. I just did a quick test on my machine. Another option is to change the default IIS error page to be your PageNotFound page. I believe that can be set on a site-by-site basis.